# Retrieve historical local datetime from UTC datetime after DST rules have changed

Tags: java, oracle, datetime

Let's say I'm using Oracle SGBD (RDBMS) and Java 8.

I have historical datetimes stored in UTC timezone, but my applications are only displaying local datetimes and my statistical calculations also apply only on local datetimes.

Now, let's say the DST rules change in Europe, [as is planned](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-may-scrap-dst.html).

What is the easiest way to keep my app and stats working ?

What I've read so far is there are timezones associated with DST rules in both [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tgbl/task_MaintainingTimeZones-0769e6.html) and [Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html), but they don't get automatic updates. Moreover, what I'd like to do is to keep the rules before and after the change, not just update the rules since I need historical stats, so I would need "Europe/Paris before change" time zone and "Europe/Paris after change" time zone, or better a timezone associated with a history of rules applying themselves as needed.

Also even if there were some convenient methods to do this in Java, it should still be fixed in Oracle too to cover all the use cases.

Here is one of the relevant historic rule changes in Chicago. DST ends last Sunday of September until 1954, then last Sunday of October from 1955 (until next rule change):

> DST Start (Clock Forward) -> DST End (Clock Backward)
>   1953  dimanche 26 avril, 02 h 00  -> dimanche 27 septembre, 02 h 00
>   1954  dimanche 25 avril, 02 h 00  -> dimanche 26 septembre, 02 h 00
>   1955  dimanche 24 avril, 02 h 00  -> dimanche 30 octobre, 02 h 00
>   1956  dimanche 29 avril, 02 h 00  -> dimanche 28 octobre, 02 h 00

P.S. : I know about [IANA historical timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), but please show how to practically use it for Oracle SGBD and Java if you have already done so.

P.P.S. : Any advice about what would be better than "UTC" to deal with this issue in future database is also welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the good news from a fellow EU citizen!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the "good" news are yet...  :)

Comment: I know only Java. After the new rules have been officially put into force, the Olson/IANA database will be updated. After that new Java versions will have the new rules, but will also still contain the historical changes. Won’t that be enough for you? If you don’t want to upgrade your Java just at that time, at a point I expect a new version of the Java [Timezone Updater Tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) will be issued so you can update your existing Java installation and obtain the same.

Comment: How will u refer to the latest or an older timezone ? I know only "Europe/Paris" for my timezone. You should make an answer for java and create an example with Chicago who has already multiple rules change.

Comment: At least there is a much longer lead time in case the change will happen - compared to sudden changes of Russia or Chile

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit We can hope for that, but even if EU decides quickly, I see no guarantee that France will also decide quickly whether to stay on summer time or standard time permanently. I keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: *Exactly* what is the data type of the column in your database?

Comment: It's an hypothetical problem, could be any type where a UTC date is stored. If you have specific advices on a type or u think there is a better type for this use case, please elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java or Oracle will apply the correct rules for any UTC date automatically - as long as you have the latest timezone data files of course.

Since you asked about an Oracle (SGBD/RDBMS) approach and mentioned Chicago, it's fairly simple to generate sample dates where the clocks changed under different rules, and see that the change is applied on the right dates (compared with the example rule change added to the question, and https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago).

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM';

with t (utc) as (
            select timestamp '1954-04-25 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1954-04-25 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1954-09-26 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1954-09-27 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '1955-04-24 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1955-04-24 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1955-10-30 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1955-10-30 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '1974-01-06 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1974-01-06 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1974-10-27 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1974-10-27 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '1975-02-23 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1975-02-23 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1975-10-26 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1975-10-26 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '1987-04-05 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1987-04-05 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1987-10-25 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '1987-10-25 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '2007-03-11 07:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2007-03-11 08:00:00 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2007-11-04 06:59:59 UTC' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2007-11-04 07:00:00 UTC' from dual
)
select utc,
  utc at time zone 'America/Chicago' as chicago
from t;
```

which gives you:

```
UTC                        CHICAGO                   
-------------------------- --------------------------
1954-04-25 07:59:59 +00:00 1954-04-25 01:59:59 -06:00
1954-04-25 08:00:00 +00:00 1954-04-25 03:00:00 -05:00
1954-09-26 06:59:59 +00:00 1954-09-26 01:59:59 -05:00
1954-09-27 07:00:00 +00:00 1954-09-27 01:00:00 -06:00
1955-04-24 07:59:59 +00:00 1955-04-24 01:59:59 -06:00
1955-04-24 08:00:00 +00:00 1955-04-24 03:00:00 -05:00
1955-10-30 06:59:59 +00:00 1955-10-30 01:59:59 -05:00
1955-10-30 07:00:00 +00:00 1955-10-30 01:00:00 -06:00
1974-01-06 07:59:59 +00:00 1974-01-06 01:59:59 -06:00
1974-01-06 08:00:00 +00:00 1974-01-06 03:00:00 -05:00
1974-10-27 06:59:59 +00:00 1974-10-27 01:59:59 -05:00
1974-10-27 07:00:00 +00:00 1974-10-27 01:00:00 -06:00
1975-02-23 07:59:59 +00:00 1975-02-23 01:59:59 -06:00
1975-02-23 08:00:00 +00:00 1975-02-23 03:00:00 -05:00
1975-10-26 06:59:59 +00:00 1975-10-26 01:59:59 -05:00
1975-10-26 07:00:00 +00:00 1975-10-26 01:00:00 -06:00
1987-04-05 07:59:59 +00:00 1987-04-05 01:59:59 -06:00
1987-04-05 08:00:00 +00:00 1987-04-05 03:00:00 -05:00
1987-10-25 06:59:59 +00:00 1987-10-25 01:59:59 -05:00
1987-10-25 07:00:00 +00:00 1987-10-25 01:00:00 -06:00
2007-03-11 07:59:59 +00:00 2007-03-11 01:59:59 -06:00
2007-03-11 08:00:00 +00:00 2007-03-11 03:00:00 -05:00
2007-11-04 06:59:59 +00:00 2007-11-04 01:59:59 -05:00
2007-11-04 07:00:00 +00:00 2007-11-04 01:00:00 -06:00
```

You can see which version of the timezone data file you're are using by querying the `v$timezone_file` view, or in recent versions the `database_properties` view.

You can read more about Oracle timezone file versions and patches in [Oracle Support Document 412160.1 (Updated DST Transitions and New Time Zones in Oracle RDBMS and OJVM Time Zone File Patches)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=412160.1).

In particular, look at section J, 'List of updated Timezones in RDBMS DST updates', which says:

> All time zone file updates are cumulative, meaning a newer RDBMS DST patch has all changes of the previous updates.
>   ...
>   In the list below the the time zones that are updated in a time zone file version are listed. Also listed is the first year of changes to the time zone rules for this time zone, and the last year (if applicable).

so it shows the historic dates are included too.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your detailed answer. AnatolijsGorbunovs is not saying anything about this, I copied your comment into his answer  :)

Comment: Alex, could you explain the choice of your example dates ? Why can we see rule changes after 1956 (end of DST in november instead of october) when the IANA file doesnt mention it ? ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz/tz-how-to.html

Comment: @Tristan - I initially just picked the first year from each page of dates from the website I linked to, where the rules seemed to have changed. I've updated to show 1954/1955 more explicitly, and to show this year. In between is more interesting. On that site, look at 1974 and 1975 as oddities; and then further rule changes from 1987 and from 2007. The page you just linked to does show those, under 'the somewhat more interesting “US” rules'.

Comment: What I understand vaguely, and which is not obvious for a non american citizen, is that "America/Chicago" is associated to various rules, some specific to Chicago, some more global to the USA, and when Chicago is back to "standard", the USA rules are applied. I guess we can just hope all of this works the same for every version of Oracle and for every versions of java.

Comment: That's not really about Oracle or Java, that's how the TZ database is set up. It's kind of covered in that link you provided, when looking at a zone record - particularly the bit about differences between zones and rules.

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html:

> This table shows which version of the Timezone data is included in the
>   different releases of the Java Development Kit (JDK) software and the
>   TZUpdater tool. Further information about the contents of the timezone
>   data releases is contained in the related request for enhancement
>   (RFE) for that release. Where a major timezone change has been
>   included in a timezone data release, this is described in the last
>   column.
>
> Latest TZdata release can be found from [IANA TZdata page](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).
>
> Since the release of TZUpdater v2.0, users can now update the tzdata
>   version in their JDK/JRE using data obtained directly from the IANA
>   tzdata releases. Refer to the TZUpdater README for more details.
>
> If you want to be informed about timezone data updates in the Java SE
>   platform and the TZUpdater tool as soon as they happen, subscribe to
>   the timezone data version RSS feed.

So basically if you need the latest time zone data all the time, upgrade the Java time zone info by using the [TZUpdater tool](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html).

**Update from Alex Poole in comment**:

> Oracle/Java will apply the appropriate rules in force on the UTC date 
>   you're trying to convert to a specific time zone. You don't need to 
>   explicitly do anything - you just need the latest version of the 
>   current+historical rules

Comment: Yep, but I don't need the "latest time zone data all the time", I also need the older timezone rules.

Comment: Is far as I know, the tzdata stores both future and historical time zone info. But you can write a test program in Java and check it if you need to be 100% sure. By "latest data" I mean all the history of time zone changes, including the latest.

Comment: Yes I know what the tzdata stores since I quote them in my question, as well as your tzdata-versions link. The question is : how to use this historical datas ? How do u refer to an historical timezone/set of rules ?

Comment: @Tristan - what do you mean by 'how to use'? Oracle/Java will apply the appropriate rules in force on the UTC date you're trying to convert to a specific time zone. You don't need to explicitly do anything - you just need the latest version of the current+historical rules. From your question, "a timezone associated with a history of rules applying themselves as needed" is what you get automatically.

Comment: Ok, nice, that was the info I was looking for about java ! If you had an answer about pure Oracle SGBD approach, it would be really useful.